MacOS Desktop application crashed Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
we are trying to build MacOS Desktop app using electron code sign-in and notarization has completed basically it is angular application but still unable to open the desktop app getting below error pop-up :
screenshot of it.
Incident Identifier: XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
CrashReporter Key:   XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
Hardware Model:      MacBook Pro (Obfuscated)
Process:             xnode [5798]
Path:                /Applications/[App Path]/Contents/MacOS/xnode
Identifier:          ai.xnode.xnode
Version:             1.0.0 (1.0.0.43313)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Default
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           ai.xnode.xnode [5056]

Date/Time:           [Redacted for Privacy]
OS Version:          macOS 14.6.1 (23G93)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: CODESIGNING 1 Taskgated Invalid Signature

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld_path_missing                      0x10dbb4010 _dyld_start + 0
1   main_executable_path_missing           0x10b395000 ???

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdx: 0x0000000000000000  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000
  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x00007ff7b4b6abf8  rip: 0x000000010dbb4010

